# Using Ocrad.js in a Cordova Application

Tags: javascript, cordova, ocr

I'm trying to use an OCR library (Ocrad.js) in my cordova android application. Using javascript, I haven't been able to make it work. Also, I can only test this app on my ancient tablet which doesn't connect to ADB, therefore I have no console. Has anyone successfully used Ocrad.js with images that are taken on-the-fly by the camera? I am storing it as a FILE_URI.

```
    $("body").load("uploadpicture.html");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('picture');
    image.src = imageURI;
    OCRPath(imageURI, function(words){
        alert(words);
    });`enter code here`
    }

    function OCRImage(image){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    alert("HELLO1");
    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
        alert("HELLO2");
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
        alert("HELLO3");

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        alert("HELLO4");

    return OCRAD(canvas);
    }

function OCRPath(url, callback){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    alert("HELLO");
    alert(OCRImage(image));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ocrad needs node.js to work. Am I right? So server side. Cordova is only client side.